# Intellitest for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellitest

Is there a way to install or integrate Intellitest in visual studio 2013?
By default it is already available in [Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823749.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IntelliTest based test case generation is not supported on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: is there an extension for this.,?

Comment: We had released the Code Digger: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fb5badda-4ea3-4314-a723-a1975cbdabb4 plugin as a "Devlabs" prototype, but that had less capabilities. In any case, that is superseded by IntelliTest.